# how to clone second row of table and add before last row with contents as blank using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following nested table.

In the table with the ID tblRating under parent table, I have three rows.

In the first row I have headers, in the second row I have three selectors and one comment box, and in the third row I have an "Add New" button.

Now when I will click on the "Add New" button, a new row should be added to the #tblRating table that is the same as that of the second row.

But new row should not copy data entered or selected in second row. And in the last cell of newly added row I want to add image or check box for deleting added row.

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr id ="trRatingId" style="display:">
    <td  colspan="2" class="hedfont">
    <table id="tblRating" class="table table table-striped table-bordered tblRating">
        <tr>
            <td><bean:message bundle="tempResource" key="lbl.Statement"/></td>
            <td><bean:message bundle="tempResource" key="lbl.Frequency"/></td>
            <td><bean:message bundle="tempResource" key="lbl.CovenantType"/></td>
            <td><bean:message bundle="tempResource" key="lbl.CovenantComment"/></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="statementId" id="statementId" class="form-control chosen-select" onchange="">
                    <ram:optionsNew initValue="0" selectValue="" initLabel="--Select--" group="<%=dynaStatement%>"/>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="frequencyId" id="frequencyId" class="form-control chosen-select" onchange="">
                    <ram:optionsNew initValue="0" selectValue="" initLabel="--Select--" group="<%=dynaFreq%>"/>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="covenantId" id="covenantId" class="form-control chosen-select" onchange="">
                    <ram:optionsNew initValue="0" selectValue="" initLabel="--Select--" group="<%=dynaCts%>"/>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" onchange="" name="comments" id="comments" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td class="edit">
            When new row will get added I want add here an image for deleting row
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="" colspan="4" align="right">
                <button type="button" name="imgAddNew" id="imgAddNew" onclick="" onfocus ="" title="Add New Record" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT:

What I found till now is

```
$("#imgAddNew").on("click", function() {
    var cloned = $(this).parents('table.tblRating').find('tr:eq(1)').clone(true);
    cloned.insertBefore($(this).parents('table.tblRating').find('tr:last-child'));

});
```

With this I am able to add new row but not able to select data in new row , when I click on select  box in new added row it point to select box of first row

Comment: When you clone the row, it will clone the `select` inputs along with its `id` and `selected` labels. So while you clone change the `id` of `select` something like `id="statementId_2"` and make the default value `selected`.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a hidden temp dummy row with the desired values and remove button/image as below :

```
<tr name="Item" id="trItemDisplayTemp" style="display: none;">
            <td name="ItemNo"></td>
            <td name="ItemDescription"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="IsPageBreak" /></td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="IsSubTitle" /></td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="IsQuestion" /></td>
            <td>
                <img onclick="deleteItem(this)" style="border: none; cursor: pointer;" src="~/Images/delete.png" />
                <img onclick="editItem(this)" style="border: none; cursor: pointer;" src="~/Images/edit.png" />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

And on page load or add button click event you can clone the above row in a variable and delete the row as below:

```
       var trItemDisplayClone = $('#trItemDisplayTemp').clone().removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
       $('#trItemDisplayTemp').remove();
```

And now you have the clone row in your variable and you can use it as you want.